# Solve these linear Lagrange Equations

Tags: dynamical-systems, euler-lagrange-equation

I am working on some practice questions and just need a bit of help with understanding the last part of the this question and the solutions.

My question is really about the last part, but here is the full question for reference:

> A simple pendulum of length $ℓ$ and mass $m$ is suspended from a pivot
>   of mass $M$ that is free to slide on a frictionless wire frame in the
>   shape of a parabola $y = ax^2$ . The pendulum moves in the plane of
>   the frame.
>
> (a) Write down the cartesian coordinates of both masses in terms of
>   $x$ and $θ$.
>
> (b) Calculate the time derivatives of the cartesian coordinates.
>
> (c) Write down the kinetic and potential energies using $x$ and $θ$ as
>   generalised coordinates.
>
> (d) Write down the Lagrangian using the approximation that $x$, $θ$
>   and their derivatives are small, and solve the corresponding linear
>   Lagrange equations.

I am ok, with parts (a) through (c), and derive the following Lagrangian which is correct:

$$L = \frac{1}{2}M \dot{x}^2(1+4a^2x^2)+\frac{1}{2}m((\dot{x}+l\cos \dot{\theta})^2 + (2ax\dot{x}+l \sin \theta \dot{\theta})^2) - (M+m)gax^2-mgl\cos\theta $$

**I am trying to understand the solutions for part (d):**

The question says "using the approximation that $x$, $\theta$ and their derivatives are small..."

And the solution says:

The Lagrangian including only the **quadratic terms** is:

$$L = \frac{1}{2}(M+m)\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{2}ml^2\dot{\theta}^2 + ml\dot{x}\dot{\theta} - (M+m)gax^2-\frac{1}{2}mgl\theta^2 $$

**First of all, I am not sure how this is derived. Secondly, why does this mean take quadratic terms?** From reading the question, it seems like I should be taking $x$, $\theta$ to be approximately $0$, but this doesn't give me the above lagrangian.

Also, from the first Lagrangian above, if I expand the terms, and collect quadratic terms, it doesn't seem to match up with the solutions. (For example , where is the $(1+4a^2x^2)$ in the 2nd lagrangian? Why is it excluded when it is attached to a quadratic term?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like small oscillation approximations (at least that's what we call it in physics), where you assume any non quadratic terms in $x,\dot{x},\theta,\dot{\theta}$ are $0$.

So, terms like $4a^2x^2\dot{x}^2$, which is quartic, would be thrown out.

Comment: ah ok that would make sense algebraically here thanks. But in general if we assume $x$ and $\theta$ are small, wouldn't quadratic terms be even smaller? Why do we just take quadratic terms? thanks.

Comment: Well, for one you have no linear terms, so quadratic terms are the largest terms you have present. You do have one constant term, but when deriving the Lagrange equations you have to take derivatives anyways, so might as well throw it out.

Comment: Thanks, just one more thing, where does the last term with the $\theta^2$ come from? Is it from the 2nd order taylor expansion for cos?

Comment: Yes, the constant term from the expansion can just be dropped because you're gonna take derivatives.